# iPhone how i can I do multiple columns in UITableView/UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, uiimageview

How I can implement the following screen.

[image]

What are ui controls can be used for implementation the same grid behavior?
I'm seeing UITableView, but it doesn't support multi columns. How can be?

Thanks,
Anatoly

Answer (score 0):

You could put three UIImageViews and three UILabels below the images per cell.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153) on how to draw grids in a UITableView.

But for your case I'd do it with interface builder for a custom UITableViewCell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about a `UITableViewCell` with three (if you count the stars it'll make six) `UIImageView`s and three `UILabel`s?

Answer (score 0):

Basing from your requirements, I think you should use AQGridView,

I found it here: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView
You can download the sample code.

I've downloaded the sample code and run it on my iPad 5.0 Simulator, here is the screenshot:
[image: AQGridView in portrait mode]

and what amazed me most is that when you switch your device to landscape mode, it automatically displays the images in four columns (to utilize the space):

[image: AQGridview in landscape mode]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing UITableViewCell to contain many cells inside and rendering each cell as needed.

Anyway, it's not a good practice to do that in your controller. You should build an external control to handle it.

Please take a look at my [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView). It uses the explained technique and produce the result that you want.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: UIGridView Example]